# match image src with regex until whitespace - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Right now I have regex which matches image `src` attribute to get the image url, but I want to regex to get the url only till first white space:

current regex: `blog_details.match(/src=(.+)/)[1]: ""`

With current regex, I get:

```
"https://res.cloudinary.com/cot/image/upload/v1xxxx878705/cz3dbifffcb6ysto7cbp.jpg layout="responsive" width="600" height="auto"/>"
```

Where this part is not required:

```
layout="responsive" width="600" height="auto"/>"
```

Comment: No double-quotes(") after jpg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a negated character class:

```
src=([^\s]+)
```

Comment: Do I have to remove: `[1]: ""` after regex which I have?

Comment: `[1]` refers to first capturing group in resulting array which you need it. I'm not sure about the rest.

Comment: I understand `^` matches first input character, but what does `backslash` does? I tried to read the docs but couldn't figure out

Comment: In very beginning of a character class, a caret negates whole character class. `[\s]` means match whitespace characters only. `[^\s]` means match anything but whitespaces. `\s` meta-character denotes to whitespace characters.

Comment: If `[^\s] means match anything but whitespaces.` then how does it stop at first `whitespace` ?

Comment: Read it this way *...match anything except whitespaces.*

Comment: Yeah it will then match this also right ? `layout="responsive" width="600" height="auto"` ?

Comment: Okay `...match anything except whitespaces` but stop `when first white space occurred`?

Comment: Since it doesn't match spaces, it won't go beyond URL.

Comment: Oh okay.. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Here is a regex that will get everything till the closing quote or whitespace:

```
/src="(.*?)(?:"|\s)/
```

```js
const
  sourceUnclosed = '<img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/cot/image/upload/v1xxxx878705/cz3dbifffcb6ysto7cbp.jpg layout="responsive" width="600" height="auto"/>',
  sourceClosed = '<img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/cot/image/upload/v1xxxx878705/cz3dbifffcb6ysto7cbp.jpg" layout="responsive" width="600" height="auto"/>',
  regex = /src="(.*?)(?:"|\s)/;
  
console.log(regex.exec(sourceUnclosed)[1]);
console.log(regex.exec(sourceClosed)[1]);
```

But like @Anil said, it looks like your HTML is missing a closing quote for the `src` attribute.

Comment: is `.jpg` is missing or I am not able to see it in the output snippet?

Comment: I'm seeing it in the console, try it with your dev tools open. Then you can see the URL in the devtools log.